# Souncloud API with a submission form

Tags: javascript, html, api, popup, soundcloud

I am trying to build a form that allows users to submit a song for promotion. The basics are that a user chooses one to three platforms; soundcloud, youtube or spotify. When they choose the platform(s) they would like to featured on, they have to follow/subscribe on those platforms.

So far, I have managed to build the form and the "Connect [platform]" buttons only show when the corresponding checkbox is selected but I am having difficulty with the API calls to Soundcloud.

I am using the JavaScript SDK and have the prebuilt commands in an html file which I am activating through my browser. The html looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Connect Soundcloud</title>
    <script src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
    <button id="scbutton" onclick="scconnectgo()">Connect Soundcloud</button>
    <script src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.0.0.js"></script>
    <script>
    function scconnectgo(){
    document.getElementById("scbutton").value="soundcloud connected";
    SC.initialize({
    client_id: 'example_client_id',
      redirect_uri: 'http://djr.kissr.com/callback.html'
      });
// initiate auth popup
    SC.connect().then(function() {
    return SC.get('/me');
    }).then(function(me) {
    alert('Hello, ' + me.username);
    });
    }
    </script>
    </script>
  </head>
<body>
<div id="target"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I load this file into my browser, the button says "connect soundcloud" which is what I want. When the button is clicked the script runs, the soundcloud connect popup shows. All good so far, but when I click connect after I've put in my details, the popup doesn't disappear. The callback.html file that I am hosting doesn't seem to work and I just copied and pasted it into a textfile and uploaded it to my KISSr dropbox folder. The page does load and it says "this popup will close..." but it doesn't.

Here is the code for the callback.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
            <title>Connect with SoundCloud</title>
        </head>
        <body onload="window.setTimeout(window.opener.SC.connectCallback, 1)">
            <b style="text-align: center;">This popup should automatically close in a few seconds</b>
        </body>
</html>
```

The window just stays open and I don't know if the script has been successful.

Any suggestions? I've seen a few problems with this before, but sadly none of them answer my question. I would really appreciate some help with this.

EDIT: I just used the 'inspect' function in Chrome and discovered that the protocols do not match. the error was: "Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://djr.kissr.com" from accessing a frame with origin "null".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "file". Protocols must match." I don't know if that helps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you running your page from a local web server or off your filesystem? Which page is that error on?

Comment: At the moment yes, but the SC authorization pop up does appear, I enter my details, I get the "this popup will close soon..." page, but it doesn't close

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have working for me on a project I am working on.

The contents of my callback.html page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Connect with SoundCloud</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <b style="text-align: center;">This popup...</b>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var sURL = window.document.URL.toString();
        window.opener.scUser.parseToken(sURL);
        window.close();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

scUser is a javascript Object with the method "parseToken" that parses 
the URL, strips out and utilizes the token (if present).

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response. Sadly, this did not work either. Would it make a difference if I had signed in using the account that I registered the app with? I have several other accounts to try if that makes a difference?

Comment: I was having the same issue and forget how I resolved it.

As far as I can remember, I could never get it to work using the body "onload" so I put the code inline as shown in my example.

Comment: I managed to resolve it. The problem was that the original html file was located on my had drive and not online. I hosted the file online and it works. I'm now having trouble with the sc.[function] commands, but that's something else entirely. Also, just to add, I did try the code your wrote above, but it didn't like that either

Answer (score 0):

This is my working login flow :

I make a remote call using Ajax to a php function to retrieve the 
url I am going to use to create a my own login window

```
public function getAuthConnect() {
  $result = "https://soundcloud.com/connect?"
    . "client_id=" . $this->getClientId(false)
    . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($this->getCallback())
    . "&response_type=code"
    . "&consumer_key=" . $this->getClientSecret();
  return $result;
}
```

This function returns me a url like this :

https://soundcloud.com/connect?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=MY_CALLBACK_URL&response_type=code&consumer_key=MY_CLIENT_SECRET_CODE

*The MY_CALLBACK_URL must match the Redirect URI for Authentication you entered for your app at soundcloud.*

I then create and open my own login pop up window
where "data" is the returned URL above

```
var myWindow = window.open(
  data, "myWindow", "width=" + w + ", height=" 
  + h + ", top=" + top + ", left=" + left);
```